# close pop-up - chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to create a quite simple chrome extention, that close a pop-up after the pop-up is loaded, and by its title. 
But for some reason the the title keeps returnen blank.

This is what i came up with.

```
{
    "name": "ReportCloser",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "run_at": "document_end" ,
        "js": ["script.js"]      // pay attention to this line
        }
    ], 
    "manifest_version":2
}
```

script.js

```
var x = document.title;
var title = "customtitle"; 

    if(x==title){
        close();

    }
        else{ }
```

I tried to move run_at: document_end before the content script, but the problem i still there.

Any tips?

Comment: The title may be set dynamically after you check it; `document_end` only guarantees that static DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Xan the title is always the same, but i think you could be right about that. 
Do you have any tips on how to close a custom pop-up?

Comment: Why do you look at the title?

Comment: @Xan Well i don't have much more to grab on really, Its the only pop-up I need to autoclose.

Comment: Can't you identify it by URL? Then you won't need a content script to begin with.

Comment: @Xan I thought about it first, but the url is changing. oh so much hassle =)

Comment: @Xan you know what, I lied to you, the URL is always the same. Will try your suggestion. 
Thanks.